# Number of surjections between finite sets (what is wrong with my solution?)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I'm trying to find the number of surjective functions from $[n]:=\{1,\dots,n\}$ onto $[m]$ and I thought I had it solved correctly as $n!\cdot m^{n-m}$, but the other questions on MSE seem to suggest the actual answer involves partitions and Stirling numbers and so on. What exactly is wrong with my solution?

> If $n<m$ there are no surjective functions. Let $n\geq m$. Each function $f:[n]\to[m]$ corresponds to a tuple $(y_1,\dots,y_n)$, where $y_i=f(i)$. Consider the set of tuples $S=\{(1,\dots,m,y_1,\dots,y_{n-m}):y_i\in[m]\}$. In order for $f$ to be surjective, its corresponding tuple $t$ must contain every element of $[m]$ at least once, therefore $t$ must be a permutation of some element of $S$. There are $m^{n-m}$ elements in $S$, therefore there are $n!\cdot m^{n-m}$ surjective functions from $[n]$ onto $[m]$.

Comment: What's your definition of a surjection? How does that relate to your formula? EG Must the first $n$ elements map onto distinct values?

Comment: @CalvinLin my definition of a surjection is the regular one, i.e. $f([n])=[m]$. My idea basically was that since the corresponding tuple must contain every element of $[m]$, after a permutation it must be of the form $(1,…,m,y_1,…,y_{n-m})$ and hence in $S$. Now that I think about it, maybe I'm counting the same functions several times, resulting an inflated answer (now I have to figure out what exactly it is I'm overcounting).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your method has a lot of double counting.

Let's look at $n=3,m=2$. You are saying there should be $2\cdot 3!=12$ sujective functions, each determined by starting with a list $(1,2,*)$, choosing $*$ to be either $1$ or $2$, and then permuting this list. Let us look at the functions this generates:

| $\,$ | $* = 1$ | $* = 2$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $(1,2,*)$ | $(1,2,1)$ | $\color{red}{(1,2,2)}$ |
| $(2,1,*)$ | $(2,1,1)$ | $(2,1,2)$ |
| $(1,*,2)$ | $(1,1,2)$ | $\color{red}{(1,2,2)}$ |
| $(2,*,1)$ | $(2,1,1)$ | $(2,2,1)$ |
| $(*,1,2)$ | $(1,1,2)$ | $(1,1,2)$ |
| $(*,2,1)$ | $(1,2,1)$ | $(2,2,1)$ |

I have highlighted one instance of a function which is counted twice by your method, but there are many more.

Comment: You are correct, I realised this only after posting my question. Would it in your opinion be feasible to try and calculate the "amount" of double-counting or should I just scrap this approach and try another way (I was just thinking maybe I could do this recursively)?

Comment: @V.Ch. The problem is, different functions are over-counted by different factors, there is no simple fix. In my example, everything was double counted, but for $n=4,m=2$, the function $(1,1,1,2)$ is overcounted by a factor of $3$, while $(1,1,2,2)$ is overcounted by a factor of $4$. The best method (IMO) uses [principle of inclusion exclusion](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=inclusion+exclusion+surjections).